# SFML - Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, sfml

создал 2 класса:

1) Window.hpp

```
#ifndef WINDOW_HPP
#define WINDOW_HPP

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Widgets/Button.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Window{
public:
    Window(){
        window.create(sf::VideoMode(width, height), "Window", sf::Style::Close);
        window.setPosition(sf::Vector2i(desktop_width/2-width/2, desktop_height/2-height/2));

        Button_void();

        while(window.isOpen()){
            while(window.pollEvent(event)){
                if(event.type==sf::Event::Closed)
                    window.close();
                if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Escape))
                    window.close();
            }

            window.clear();
            window.display();
        }
    }

    void Button_void(){
        button.setSize(200, 200);
        button.setBackgroundColor(255, 231, 0);
        button.setPosition(0, 0);
    }
private:
    sf::Button button;

    const int width=800;
    const int height=800;

    const int desktop_width=sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode().width;
    const int desktop_height=sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode().height;

    sf::RenderWindow window;
    sf::Event event;
};

#endif // WINDOW_HPP
```

2) Button.hpp

```
#ifndef BUTTON_HPP
#define BUTTON_HPP

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace sf{
    class Button : public sf::RectangleShape{
    public:
        void setSize(float width, float height){
            Button::setSize(width, height);
        }
        void setPosition(float x, float y){
            Button::setPosition(x, y);
        }
        void setBackgroundColor(int r, int g, int b){
            Button::setFillColor(sf::Color(r, g, b));
        }
    };
}

#endif // BUTTON_HPP
```

Код компиляции:

```
COMPILER = g++
FILENAME = Program.cpp
OUTPUT = Program
PARAMS = -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-system -lsfml-window

output:
    ${COMPILER} ${FILENAME} -o ${OUTPUT} ${PARAMS}
```

Ощибка: Segmentation Fault

Помогите пж :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не вижу где у вас SegFault получается, но вот такие вызовы приводят к бесконечному самовызову (рекурсии) функций:

```
class Button : public sf::RectangleShape{
    public:
        void setSize(float width, float height){
            Button::setSize(width, height);
```

Видимо надо так:

```
class Button : public sf::RectangleShape{
    public:
        void setSize(float width, float height){
            sf::RectangleShape::setSize(width, height);
```

Остальные функции необходимо исправить аналогично

Comment: Спасибо, всё отлично работает!